# Using bracket notation with AngularJS URL to pass state in a URL query search

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

A standard for passing state vie URL is to use bracket notation. Although it is possible to configure ui-router to use JSON with curly brackets but it doesn't allow for bracket notation to describe objects.

For example, `https://example.com/search?filter[name]=funkymonky&filter[count]=10` should be parsed to this object:

```
filter: {
    name: 'funkymonky',
    count: 10
}
```

This is the specification for JSON API. Most server web application frameworks accept this.

What do I do with ui-router?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-href property in the html and inyect de scope i dont know if this help you ...

```
$scope.filter = {
    name: 'funkymonky',
    count: 10
}
<a ng-href="https://example.com/search?{{filter.name}}=funkymonky&{{filter.count}}=10">Link</a>
```

Comment: I want ui-router to encode and decode the url query search string according to the same specification the rest of the web is using in particular $.params() in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/